# need with if Stopping method first if to if number tow

Tags: c#

hello I need a solution to my problem
How can I go to another if
When his work ends
It does not operate if number 2
To when the first is completed
I also want to jump over it to complete the rest of the code
I have used ( goto )
But it didn’t work. I don’t know what to do in this case. Please help me, thank you

```
 if (listBox3.Items[m].ToString() == errorMessage2)
                        {
                        
                        writerWCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
                        listBox2.Items.Add(data[i]);
                           
                            break;
                            


                        }
                        
                    }
                    ///////////////// i need go here after found error message in first (if)
                   
                    {
                            if (listBox3.Items[m].ToString() == errorMessage2)
                            {

                                writerWCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
                                listBox2.Items.Add(data[i]);

                            }

                        
                    }
              
                Thread.Sleep(7000);

                writerCCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
                if (address != Clipboard.GetText())
                {
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save this error ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        writerWCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
                        writerWCC.Close();
                        writerCCC.Close();
                        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
                    }
                    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(data[i]); break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(data[i]);
                }
            }
            writerWCC.Close();
            writerCCC.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Execution is complete.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input Files are not selected.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. It is very hard to understand your question and to read your code example. Could you reformat your code and remove unnecessary line breaks? I see 2 closing brackets after some line breaks but only 1 opening bracket at the beginning for example.

Comment: Furthermore please use some proper punctuation. Even though you´re not native speaker - least of us are - you should try to make your question fit SOs guidelines, which are proper english, formatting and a complete description of how your attemps failed your expactations.

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Although d4zed has provided an answer similar to what I was going to offer, the code you provided appears to be short of your outer loop conditions showing your "m" and "i" parts.  If the answer does not solve your question, please re-edit your original post and put as much of complete code as you have, especially the loop controls.  Do not try to put answer in comment, but just EDIT your existing post with changes.

Answer (score 0):

As Mono and HimBromBeere already mentioned, your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I will try anyway.

It seems like your want to know later in your code, if a certain error message was found. You can simply remember this in a bool variable, for example:

```
bool errorMessage2WasFound = false;

for (int m = 0; m < listBox3.Items.Count; m++)
{
     if (listBox3.Items[m].ToString() == errorMessage2)
     {                 
         writerWCC.WriteLine(data[i]);
         listBox2.Items.Add(data[i]);
         errorMessage2WasFound = true;
         break;
     }
}

if (errorMessage2WasFound)
{
   // do what you want to do in this case
}
```